Integration of characteristic function of level set
I have a problem understanding an identity on a proof I am  reading:
Let $f,g\in L^1\left(U\right)$ where $U$ is open and bounded.  Define
$$E_t^1=\{x\in U; f(x)\gt t\},\quad E_t^2=\{x\in U; g(x)\gt t\}$$ Whys is
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\lvert\chi_{E_t^1}(x)-\chi_{E_t^2}(x)\rvert dt= \int_{min\{f(x),g(x)\}}^{max\{f(x),g(x)\}} dt=\lvert f(x)-g(x) \rvert$$
?
Any help would be appreciated.

Step 1 : If $f(x)\geq g(x)$, then $$|f(x)-g(x)|=f(x)-g(x)=\int_{g(x)}^{f(x)}\,\mathrm d t.$$
Same, if $g(x)\geq f(x)$, then $$|f(x)-g(x)|=g(x)-f(x)=\int_{f(x)}^{g(x)}\,\mathrm d t.$$
Therefore $$|f(x)-g(x)|=\int_{\min\{f(x),g(x)\}}^{\max\{f(x),g(x)\}}\,\mathrm d t.$$
Step 2 :
$$|\chi_{E_t^1}(x)-\chi_{E_t^2}(x)|=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }x\in E_t^1\Delta E_t^2, \\ 0& \text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$
where $A\Delta B:=(A\cup B)\setminus(A\cap B)$. Therefore, $$|\chi_{E_t^1}(x)-\chi_{E_t^2}(x)|=1\iff \min\{f(x),g(x)\}\leq t<\max\{f(x),g(x)\}.$$
Combining both steps allows you to conclude.
